# Opportunity Team - Role Hierarchy?

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-teams

If I share an opportunity with a user via opportunity team, only the user will have access or his role hierarchy has access as well?

Answer (score 2):

If you share Opportunity or any standard object record with a user or his role.All users in above hierarchy will have access to that record.

> you can disable the Grant Access Using Hierarchies option for a custom object.

But You can't remove Grant Access Using Hierarchies for standard objects.